# See the source IP address of failed login attempt in parse-server logs

Tags: parse-server

I am trying to get some value out of parse-server login attempts for monitoring purposes. I find there is a lack of information in those logs. For example, there is an Parse.Errror() thrown when the username/password doesn't match.

But in the error itself, there is no indication of the source-ip address, from which the attempt was made. And that is a shame, because it can be useful for watching if somebody is trying to attack certain accounts.

I am trying to find a way, how to get this information to logs, without a need to patch parse-server. The loggerAdapter.js that I use doesn't have access to the `request` itself, so I can't read that information from there to log. In other words, from the logger, i have no clue who did the request, if that information is not already passed.

I can only implement some custom logging in case of cloud-functions.

I would be happy for any insights.

Thanks, Lukas

Comment: I don't see a way to do this as of Parse Server 3.9. You can however open a PR to add a trigger for this. It should be fairly straight forward, just look into `UsersRouter.js` of parse server and add the trigger in `_authenticateUserFromRequest(req)`.